# How can I instantiate a defined type from a manifest in my Ruby-based custom type?

Tags: puppet

I'm writing a custom Puppet resource type in Ruby and want to use a type from another module. This other type is defined in Puppet code.

From the documentation, I can do:

```rb
Puppet::Type.type(:file).new(file_opts)
```

This works for types defined in ruby, but not ones defined in `.pp` files using

```
define sysctl (){...}
```

This is the basic Ruby type definition. I'm overriding `generate` to eventually add an additional resource alongside my custom one. This is how the `type(:file)` example above seems to work:

```rb
Puppet::Type.newtype(:network_interface) do
  ensurable

  newparam(:name) do
    isnamevar
    desc 'The name of the physical network device'
  end

  def create
  end

  def generate
    [Puppet::Type.type('sysctl').new(
      name: "net.ipv4.conf.eth1.promote_secondaries",
      value: 1
    )]
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
Network_interface[eth1]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'generate': undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

I've dug through the Puppet code to try and understand how Puppet creates types from the `define` form, but no luck.

Comment: I'm not confident that this can be made to work at all, but it's a bit suspicious on its face that the type name you've given is at top scope (which indeed matches the definition stub).  Is the manifest containing the definition named and located correctly for that?

Comment: Good question, but yes it is. I've continued looking at this and I increasingly agree that it's not possible, not without writing another module to do it that will cal private Puppet Ruby APIs.

Comment: Yeah I also am not confident that a custom type could invoke a defined resource type given that custom types are loaded during pluginsync and defined resource types are autoloaded later, unless I am wrong.

Comment: Additionally the `generate` method functionality for a presumed corresponding attribute (although I do not see it marked as a property or parameter anywhere) seems unusual. Would you not want to use some kind of base provider mixin to do this instead?

Comment: This approach works fine if I do `Puppet::Type.type('file').new(file_opts)`. I think you're right about the ordering of pluginsync etc. Sounds like this one isn't doable.